# Error System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Tags: c#

Soy nueva con este tema de los servicios SOAP, estoy tratando de encontrar el error en este código, el código no lo escribí yo, pero tengo que solucionar este problema.

```
var soapString = ConstructSoapRequestFactura(request);
var ms = new MemoryStream();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPAction2);
  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2000);
  var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
  Uri uri = new Uri(SOAPAction);
  using (var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content)) 
  {
   var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var serxml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(soapResponse.GetType());
   serxml.Serialize(ms, soapResponse);
   string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(soapResponse);
   XNamespace ns = "";
   IEnumerable<XElement> responses = doc.Descendants(ns + "Status");
```

.....

al ejecuarlo me aparece el error : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: Deberías poner algo mas de la excepción que te esta lanzando. `TaskAwaiter``1.GetResult()` es donde te está lanzando la excepcion, no la excepción en si. De todas formas, yo comprobaría que el servicio que estás consultando no te esta dando algun timeout o algo asi.